# Have C# Regex.IsMatch return false if doesn't match entire input string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently trying to implement a check for a regex matching an input string, which i would like to only validate letters a-z, (lower or caps) excluding all numbers, special characters...

However, if the regex matches partially, `Regex.Match(input)` will return true. I would like it to return false unless the entire input string is valid, how would i go about this?

Here is an example if how i would like it to work, the Regex pattern shown is what i'm currently using.

```
Regex expression = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]*");

if(!expression.IsMatch("example123")) { /* do something */ }
```

As it is right now, the Regex will match up to "example", and still return true, even though it contains "123" at the end.

Comment: If you want to do it with a regex, use `"^[a-zA-Z]*$"`, or even better `@"^[a-zA-Z]*\z"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - If you're going to use `\z`, wouldn't it also be better to use `\A` in place of `^`? I've actually never used `\z` or `\A`, so I'm curious.

Comment: `\A` is only good if the user can modify the regex and pass the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option (say, with the help of `(?m)` inline modifier). If the pattern cannot be modified, `^` is equally good.